# Output one occurence of a character in a string c#

Tags: java, sorting, ascii

This program should output only one occurrence of a character in a string then specify the number of occurrence in that string. It should be sorted in ascending order depending on the number of occurrences of that particular character. It's working except on the `(char)i` part. Does it have something to do with ASCII codes or something?

Desired Output:
b: 1
d:1
a:2
s:2

Code's output: 
ü: 1
ý: 1
þ: 2
ÿ: 2

```
public class HuffmanCode {
    static String string;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        string = input.nextLine();

        int count[] = countOccurence(string);
        Arrays.sort(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if (count[i] > 0)
                System.out.println((char)i + ": " + count[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] countOccurence(String str){
        int counts[] = new int[256];

        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            char charAt = str.charAt(i);
            counts[(int)charAt]++;
        }

        return counts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `Arrays.sort(count);`

Comment: @saka1029 i want to sort it in ascending order. should i just hard code the sort so it would work?

Comment: you need an object that holds the char and the count, make a List of it and sort that Lis. By the way: it is java, not c#, isn't it?

Comment: The position in the count array provides the letter and the value at that position provides the number of occurrences of that letter. For example: if counts[65] = 2, then the char is 'A' and 'A' was seen twice. When you sort the counts array, you move the values around which messes up this correspondence and you get gibberish.

Comment: 256! What about the other 120,000 or so [characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list and sort it instead of sorting `count`.

```
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > 0)
            list.add(new int[] {i , count[i]});
    }
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(a -> a[1]));
    for (int[] a : list) {
        System.out.println((char)a[0] + ": " + a[1]);
    }
```

Comment: @joel314 's answer is shorter than this.  His answer does not require `countOccurence` and it can count character over 255 correctly.

Comment: Thanks @saka1029 Yes, technically it's just done in one line of code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you could use the `Stream` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and do something like this:

```
    String input = "ababcabcd" ; 

    input.chars() // split the string to a stream of int representing the chars
        .boxed()  // convert to stream of Integer
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c->c,Collectors.counting())) // aggregate by counting the letters
        .entrySet() // collection of entries (key, value), i.e. char, count
        .stream()   // corresponding stream
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // sort by value, i.e. by number of occurence of letters
        .forEach(e->System.out.println((char)(int)e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue())); // Output the result
```

The result would be:

```
d: 1
c: 2
a: 3
b: 3
```

I hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
Suppose your input is

```
        String input = "ababc\u0327abçd" ;
```

We would have in that case `ababçabçd`as input and we need normalization to make sure we properly count the letters that are the same, with different representations. To achieve that, we preprocess the `input`string using [Normalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html), which was introduced in JDK6:

```
        input = Normalizer.normalize(input, Form.NFC);
```

Comment: Add string normalization and this answer is golden. (`test = "façadefac\u0327ade"`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TreeMap` with a combination of custom `Comparator`

Here's an example

```
String test = "ABBCCCDDDDEEEEEFFFFFF";

Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Character c : test.toCharArray()) {
    if (!map.containsKey(c)) map.put(c, 0);
    map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
}

Map<Character, Integer> tMap = new TreeMap<>(new MyComparator(map));
tMap.putAll(map);

for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : tMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

And here's the implementation of `MyComparator`

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    Map<Character, Integer> map;

    public MyComparator(Map<Character, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (map.get(o1).equals(map.get(o2)))
            return 1;
        else
            return (map.get(o1)).compareTo(map.get(o2));
    }
}
```

Comment: the sorting is missing

Comment: No need to sort. `TreeMap` does the sorting automatically

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood the question. I thought OP wants to sort by the "key"

Comment: Thank you! I think this will be really helpful given that i'm coding Huffman Tree.